# Calculus 1 question

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the normal line to the curve  $y = \sqrt{x}$ that is parallel to the line $6x + y = 1$.

Comment: i don't know how to do it

Comment: Hint: What point of the derivative of $y=\sqrt{x}$ has the same value of the inclination of the line ?

Comment: He wants the normal to match the line, not the tangent. For that you also need the fact that two lines are perpendicular when their slopes satisfy $m_1 = \frac{-1}{m_2}$.

Comment: i put everything in y - y0 = m(x-x0) then i got y = -6x+1/8

Comment: Where did you get 1/8 from? The problem has 1 as the intercept? But that is acually unimportant. What you need to know is the slope of this line, which is also the slope of your normal line. Then use the perpendicular slopes formula I gave to find the slope of the tangent line to $y = \sqrt x$.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about the normal of $y=\sqrt x$? What properties do you know a normal parallell to the line $6x+y=1$ must possess? Can you find a point where the normal of $y=\sqrt x$ have these properties?

Comment: i got 1/6 for the slope. can you please give me a full solution because i am so confused right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is $y=-6x+1$ and the normal has the same slope, so the tangent has a slope of $\frac{1}{6}$, i.e. $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Do the rest

---

Edit: Since you're confused;

$y=\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ so: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}-1}=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2x^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Now $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the slope of the tangent, and we know that we want it to be $\frac{1}{6}$, so:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{6}\; ,\; \; x=9$$

That's the $x$ value on the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$, so the $y$ value is $y=\sqrt{9}=3$.

So normal at that point goes through $\left( 9,3 \right)$ and has a slope of $-6$.

The equation is: $$y-3=-6\left( x-9 \right)$$

Comment: i did it but its still wrong. so can you please give me a solution? :)

Comment: you got $x=9$ and $y=3$ right?

Comment: After that use: $y-y_{0}=m\left( x-x_{0} \right)$ and don't take $m=\frac{1}{6}$ because that's the slope of the tangent; take $m=-6$

Comment: Set the derivative of $\sqrt x = 1/6$ and solve for $x$. Call the solutions $x_0$. This tells you the point on the curve where the normal must be taken to have a slope of $-6$. Now that $y_0 = \sqrt {x_0}$ to find the y-value for this point. Now you have the point $(x_0, y_0)$ that the normal passes through and the slope of the normal, and you've already shown that you know the point-slope form of the equation of a line.

Comment: i got y=-6x + 57. is it right?

Comment: It is, good job

Comment: but can you tell me how can you get x=9 and y=3?

Comment: Okay i'll write it up..